# start sshd on ubuntu-phablet BQ Aquaris

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sshd

I would like to access my Pad from another computer, but there seems to be no sshd client running.

How can I start an sshd and set the password to access it from my home network?

Answer (score 0):

To start an ssh server open the terminal app and issue the command `sudo service ssh start`.

By default only key-pair authentication is enabled so you'll have to add your public key (from the other machine) to the file `/home/phablet/.ssh/authorized_keys` on your tablet to be able log on via ssh.

This works fine for me so I haven't investigated setting up password authentication.